# How can I control the subdivision per polygon?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a simple low poly base mesh of a town and I'm trying to use *Geometry Nodes* to procedurally add details to all the houses. I'm trying to find a way to subdivide faces based on polygon area, such as only subdividing large polygons.

I thought that after the *Split Edges* node I would be able to control the subdivision individually, but that doesn't work. The following setting changes the subdivision when the area changes, but not on a polygon basis.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: GNsetup]

Comment: i think this isn't possible because subdivide only has a circle as input which means: one value - so one geometry - not multiple

Comment: Well, you see the dashed line coming out of the _Face Area_ node... this is a field ouptput, meaning it puts out multiple values (one for each face). The _Level_ input on the _Subdivide Mesh_ node has a circular shape, which means in all cases it only accepts single values. You cannot set multiple levels in one _Subdivide Mesh_ node, same goes for _Subdivision Surface_. EDIT: @Chris exactly ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

but what you could do, is use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks for elaborating this, I had no time to do it. I would have added some other exotic ideas like maybe three steps of area sizes and then joined together and maybe even... ah well, doesn't matter :D

Comment: thank you     :) at first i thought it is impossible....but...GN is already much better than its reputation ;)

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for! Creating different subdivision levels for different area sizes should be easy now based on this.

Comment: glad i could help